# Why can I not take the substring of this string?

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception

From this functional code,

```
String line = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (line != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        checklistList.add(fillList("list", line));
        i++;
    }
```

the line looks something like checklist(date).txt, and I want it to just be the date. The obvious solution to me was

```
String line = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (line != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        checklistList.add(fillList("list", line.substring(13, 29)));
        i++;
    }
```

However this results in the error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int, int)' on a null object reference
```

What can be done to fix this? Running on android if it makes a difference.

Comment: `.. on a null object reference ..` Probably the iteration has reached the end of file, and at that point, the line variable be `null`. It says that the object is `null` in the error statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if line is null before try to substring it.

```
String line = "";
int i = 0;
while (line != null) {
    line = br.readLine();    
    if (line != null) {    // CHeck if line is null or not
        checklistList.add(fillList("list", line.substring(13, 29)));
    }
    i++;
}
```

**Note:** I don't know any additional details of your code but perhaps you have to check also if the line is long enough to substring it at the positions you indicated.

Comment: Or just move the readLine() to the loop like, `while((line = br.readLine()) != null)`

Comment: @COdebender Yes.... many possible implentation are available. This one only put enphasis on the check on null value. A little difference is that in this solution i is incremented by 1 last time. I don't know if the intent was this one or not. So there is a difference between my code and yours

Answer (score 1):

as @David mentioned you need to check if line is not `null`

here is a standard approach for it

```
String line = "";
int i = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //set line then check for null
    checklistList.add(fillList("list", line.substring(13, 29)));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Need to check length of the string to ignore java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range